# Question about design rationale / history of CSS feature closed as "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

My question [Inline HTML elements don't allow setting “width” - why is that?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/404472/inline-html-elements-dont-allow-setting-width-why-is-that) was just closed as "opinion-based".

I'm a bit confused as to why. I'm not asking for opinion, I'm asking for the rationale and history behind a design decision. I thought software and API design was squarely on-topic here.

Also, there is a fair number of (excellent, IMHO) similar questions about why certain APIs or systems are the way they are, such as:

- [Why is 80 characters the 'standard' limit for code width?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width)
- [Why is 0 false?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198284/why-is-0-false)
- [What is the history of why bytes are eight bits?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120126/what-is-the-history-of-why-bytes-are-eight-bits)
- [Block elements vs inline elements in HTML: why the distinction?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61345/block-elements-vs-inline-elements-in-html-why-the-distinction) (this one is even about CSS, too)

Unfortunately, none of the five close-voters left a comment explaining their decision. So why was is considered opinion-based? How could I ask about this design decision in a way that is on-topic?

Comment: Similar question: [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio)

Answer (score 3):

I'm reopening this question unless someone has a good reason why it shouldn't be. We have [guidance about history type questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/is-programming-history-on-topic), which (as far as I can remember or find) hasn't been superseded by newer guidance and we have a number of other open and unlocked history questions.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast :-).